# Parse specific XML attribute from one file and append it to another iff another attribute is present in the second file

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I have three XML Files (samples below). I've named the files with their respective values of the `audioId` attribute. Therefore, the files in question would be called `93.xml` and `2137.xml`:

93.xml:

```
<word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" Stage="0" Use="P,L" audioId="93" />
```

2173.xml:

```
<word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" Stage="0" Use="P,L" audioId="2137" />
```

mainDataSet.xml:

```
<word id="2137" title="over" level="1" grouping="Sight Words" YRule="0" MagicE="0" SoftC="0" doublevowel="0" longvowel="0" displayorder="101" silentletters="0"/>
```

File `mainDataSet.xml` contains ~3,000 entries. I've only provided one entry from it for the purpose of this question.

My question is regarding how I would append the `title` attribute from `mainDataSet.xml` to the `word` tag in `2173.xml` from `mainDataSet.xml` if the `id` matches in both the files (or even if the `id` in `mainDataSet.xml` matches the file *name*). For example, in the samples I've provided, the output should be:

```
<word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" Stage="0" Use="P,L" audioId="2137" title="over" />
```

To parse my XML from `mainDataSet.xml`, I'm currently doing:

```
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('mainDataSet.xml').getroot()
for atype in e.findall('word'):
    print(atype.get('title'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an attribute, use the [`.attrib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) dictionary. Here is a sample code that loops over the `word` elements inside the `mainDataSet.xml`, retrieves the `id` attribute value, parses the appropriate XML file (`93.xml` and `2173.xml` in this case), updates the `word` element and dumps the tree back to the file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


e = ET.parse('mainDataSet.xml').getroot()
for word in e.findall('word'):
    word_id = word.attrib.get("id")
    if word_id:
        filename = "%s.xml" % word_id
        e_word = ET.parse(filename)
        e_word.getroot().attrib['title'] = word.attrib.get('title')
        e_word.write(filename)
```

Sample `mainDataSet.xml` that I've used:

```
<words>
    <word id="2137" title="over" level="1" grouping="Sight Words" YRule="0" MagicE="0" SoftC="0" doublevowel="0" longvowel="0" displayorder="101" silentletters="0"/>
    <word id="93" title="something else" level="1" grouping="Sight Words" YRule="0" MagicE="0" SoftC="0" doublevowel="0" longvowel="0" displayorder="101" silentletters="0"/>
</words>
```

Here is what I've got after running the script:

- `93.xml`:

  ```
  <word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" Stage="0" Use="P,L" audioId="93" title="something else" />
  ```
- `2173.xml`:

  ```
  <word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" Stage="0" Use="P,L" audioId="2137" title="over" />
  ```

Comment: Perfect. Danke! I'll go through this and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

For OP or future readers, consider an XSLT 1.0 solution which Python can run using the `lxml` module. As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) is a special purpose language (whose script is a well-formed xml file) designed to manipulate XML files. The script is portable to other general purpose languages (Java, PHP, C#), XSLT processors (Saxon, Xalan), even command line interpreters (Bash, PowerShell). Specifically, for this question, XSLT maintains the [`document()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function which can access nodes in external xml files for comparison needs like the ids.

**Input** *(adding root tags)*

mainDataSet.xml

```
<root>
   <word id="2137" title="over" level="1" grouping="Sight Words" YRule="0" 
         MagicE="0" SoftC="0" doublevowel="0" longvowel="0" 
         displayorder="101" silentletters="0"/>
</root>
```

2137.xml

```
<root>
    <word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" 
          Stage="0" Use="P,L" audioId="2137" />
</root>
```

93.xml

```
<root>
   <word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7"
         Stage="0" Use="P,L" audioId="93" />
</root>
```

**XSLT** Script *(save externally as .xsl; read in .py; assumes all XML files are in same directory)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="word"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="word">    
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:if test="@audioId = document('mainDataSet.xml')/root/word/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
          <xsl:value-of select="document('mainDataSet.xml')/root/word/@title"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** Script

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')
for i in ['2137', '93']:
    dom = ET.parse('{}.xml'.format(i))

    # TRANSFORM XML
    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    newdom = transform(dom)

    # PRETTY PRINT OUTPUT
    tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True)
    print(tree_out.decode("utf-8"))

    # SAVE TO FILE
    xmlfile = open('{}.xml'.format(i),'wb')
    xmlfile.write(tree_out)
    xmlfile.close()
```

**Output**  *(using posted data)*

2173.xml

```
<root>
  <word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" Stage="0" 
        Use="P,L" audioId="2137" title="over"/>
</root>
```

93.xml

```
<root>
  <word BloomsTaxonomy="1,2,3" DictationGroupid="i-e combination List 7" Stage="0" 
        Use="P,L" audioId="93"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Purr-fect. Both these solutions work! I'll go through them and let you know. Danke!

Comment: I ended up using @alecxe 's solution. This one is also a pretty good idea! Thanks all the same!